# Understanding why hotspots from Getis-Ord Gi* are perfect circles?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, spatial-statistics, hot-spot

I've been using optimized hotspot analysis and the hotspot maps I am getting back frequently have rings of perfectly circular hotspots.

Is this because of the way Getis-Ord Gi* tests calculates neighborhood sums?

Natural events don't often happen with perfect symmetry and when I look at the underlying data, it doesn't appear to be set out in circles. I feel like it must be due to the statistical processes underlying hot spot analysis.

[image: Circular Hotspots Example]

Comment: Have you reviewed [How Hot Spot Analysis (Getis-Ord Gi*) works](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-statistics-toolbox/h-how-hot-spot-analysis-getis-ord-gi-spatial-stati.htm)?